# Call an event inside a function c#

Tags: c#

How do i call an event inside a function? Because i am having an error `Object reference not set to instance of an object` and the error pointed at : `_e.RowIndex`

And i was wondering how do i call an event inside a function. Now what i could is call an event from `new EventHandler(....)` , but now i want call a event inside a function and it is gave me the error `Object reference not set to instance of an object`

Here is the code:

```
private void UpdateQuantityDataGridView(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataGridViewCellEventArgs _e = null;

  cmdSelect.Parameters.Add( "ProductCode" , System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar ) ;
  cmdSelect.Parameters[ "ProductCode" ].Value = dataGridView1[ "Product Code" , _e.RowIndex].Value;

}
```

Is the code above was correct way to do that?

**EDITED**

This is where i called a function `UpdateQuantityDataGridView`:

```
if (_choice.comboBox1.Text == "English")
                {
                    System.Media.SoundPlayer _sounds = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                    _sounds.Play();
                    MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully!", "Updated");

                    ShowButtons(sender, e);

                    DisableColumnEdited(sender, e);

                    UpdateQuantityDataGridView(sender, e);
                }
```

Here is my case:

When user editing data in DataGridView, and user click "OK" button, the code above will execute and it update the database from DataGridView, that's why i want to access `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` inside a function. I cannot accomplish and work when i call that by using `new EventHandler(....)`

Comment: `_e = null` deferencing a null reference will leads to `NullReferenceException`. What are you trying to acheive? What would you like `_e.RowIndex` to return?

Comment: `_e.RowIndex` is to tell the program which row that i have been selected from DataGridView

Comment: Show me your code where you call `UpdateQuantityDataGridView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting `_e` to `null` then trying to use it which will create a `NullReferenceException` (as you've discovered).

I think you want to cast `e` as `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` instead of creating a new variable.

```
private void UpdateQuantityDataGridView(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  cmdSelect.Parameters.Add( "ProductCode" , System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar ) ;
  cmdSelect.Parameters[ "ProductCode" ].Value = dataGridView1[ "Product Code" , ((DataGridViewCellEventArgs)e).RowIndex].Value;

}
```

(As mentioned in comments, this assumes you're passing an instance of  `DataGridViewCellEventArs` for `e`.)

Comment: that definitely won't work because `e` is of type `EventArgs`.

Comment: i tried this `dataGridView["Product Code", (DataGridViewCellEventArgs)_e.RowIndex].Value`

But the `_e` does not exist in current content.

Comment: @neoistheone and `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` is derived from `EventArgs` so it could work, if that is what is being passed in as `e`, it all depends on how `UpdateQuantityDataGridView` is being called, we need to see the code where either he subscribes to the event or calls the function himself.

Comment: @Kaoru Don't use `_e`, use `e`.

Comment: when i use `e`, `e` is type of `EventArgs`, so the `RowIndex` does not contain in `EventArgs`

Comment: @Kaoru Sorry, I forgot some () in my answer that would make the cast useless.  Try the updated code.

Answer (score 4):

You are setting the variable _e to null. Then, you are referencing _e.RowIndex when you never set.

Comment: I removed the "can't leave a comment yet" bit.  What you said is the answer, no need to leave it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `_e` to `null`.

Then, you try to access its `RowIndex` property, which is what is throwing the `NullReferenceException`.

All your code sample is trying to do is add a parameter to `cmdSelect`. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Question can be in comments